# how to get dictionary same order as same i am getting from json in objective c

Tags: objective-c

i am parsing json and what i get set of dictionary but after parsing it will automatically change it order. i just need same order as same i am getting from json parsing.

**NOTE:** i want to make one functionality which depends on dictionary order, i don't want to make it manually. so it will not need to make it every-time to do.it will help to change dynamically in future

Example:
**From Json:**

```
Section:
{
  category:{},
  location:{},
  vehicle_type:{},
  mode_type:{}
}
```

**after convert into NSDicationary:**

```
Section:
{
  vehicle_type:{}
  category:{},
  location:{},
  mode_type:{}

}
```

Thanks

Comment: You can't, because `Dictionary` is not an ordered collection.

Comment: @mag_zbc, so there is no predefine thing to do, only i can make it manually?

Comment: @manoj Dictionaries are not ordered collections in Objective-C
Use this to achieve this https://github.com/nicklockwood/OrderedDictionary

Answer (score 0):

Order of `key:value` doesn't matter for JSON, as you can directly access value with the help of key string. An dictionary does not support indexing of elements, so you can't.

Comment: but i want to make one functionality which depends on dictionary order, i don't want to make it manually. so it will not need to make it every-time to do.

Comment: You can share, what you want to do with ordered elements of dictionary. We can help you in that direction.

Comment: there is functionality in app, where we are showing category  in  a way as i get in json response. so i there is any changes in category , it will automatically reflect all changes into app as well

Comment: So, i think you should use an array of JSON (ask your web service developer/provider to provide you an array of JSON in an order that you want to show in your app. And this is the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries are not ordered collections. On other hand, arrays are.

**Note, if you don't have access over the json format, you got no guarantees about the order of elements, if you don't have hardcoded logic in your app.**

Having said that, let's take a deeper look into your case. It happens that you have one main object in your json that is `Section`. What is more, you have 4 ordered properties of this object that are of specific kind of their own: `0: category; 1: location; 2: vehicle_type; 3: mode_type`. So here comes the good part: just change your json to look something like this:

```
Section:
[
  {
     title: "category",
     value: {}
  },
  {
     title: "location",
     value: {}
  },
  {
     title: "vehicle_type",
     value: {}
  },
  {
     title: "mode_type",
     value: {}
  }
]
```

Having this json, you just go through the Section ordered elements, check the title of the element, and create the corresponding Object. This way you can achieve what you are after.